# an alternative to GMM?

Tags: econometrics, vector-autoregression, endogeneity, generalized-moments

Dear StackExchange Users,

I am currently working on my PhD thesis and one of the chapter deals endogeneity in the data.
I have *N* the number of individual (here country) = 11 and *T* the time dimension = 78. I have 6 variables which are mostly endogeneous. To deal with that without having to use other data as Instrumental Variables, the syst. GMM uses the lagged values of the variables (in difference) as instrumental variables.
However, GMM works fine when *N > T* which is not the case here. I was thinking of a panel VAR but it relies on GMM.

 I find myself blocked at this level, and wanted to know if any readers here would have any idea of alternative to GMM, or recommendation ?
Thank you !

Comment: Did you find any bibliography focused on high  dimensionality problems ?

Comment: Hello partizanos, I looked for it following your comment and find interesting models and methods. unfortunately, rather than an large-N large-T situation, I am more in a large-T small-N one.